# Error installing Micropython libraries with Thonny IDE

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I am trying to install umqtt.simple onto my Thonny IDE using Micropython. I have a Raspberry Pi Pico W with Micropython already installed on both the device and Thonny, and Micropython is the selected interpreter in the bottom right.

Whenever I try to install a library however, I get met with the following error:

```
Collecting micropython-umqtt.simple
  Using cached micropython-umqtt.simple-1.3.4.tar.gz (4.0 kB)
ERROR: micropython-umqtt.simple from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/cf/697e3418b2f44222b3e848078b1e33ee76aedca9b6c2430ca1b1aec1ce1d/micropython-umqtt.simple-1.3.4.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
Error: process returned with code 1
```

I have also tried installing the .tar.gz file and downloading the library locally, and I get met with the same error.

Comment: How are you trying to install it?  You didn't show is the command you typed.  https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html

Comment: I am installing it through PyPi installer that is built into Thonny. When I search for umqtt.simple and click "Install", I get presented with the error posted originally

Comment: Are you using the MicroPython extension?  Micropython does not support pip, so you have to use something else.

Comment: See around time `07:47` in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sPPxIq4hg8

Comment: @MarkSetchell this seemed to help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `upip` and not `pip`. It works exactly like the normal `pip`. To install `foo`: `upip install foo` instead of `pip install foo`